# Aggregate counts up until every ISO WEEK

Tags: postgresql

I am stuck with creating a column that would show aggregated numbers for number of created contacts.

I would like to achieve what it is visible in column C
[image]

```
SELECT x.date_period, count(x.vid) contacts FROM
(
SELECT c.firstname as owner, c.vid, to_char(c.properties__createdate__value::date, 'IYYYIW') as date_period
FROM "hmy"."contacts" as c
) x
group by x.date_period
```

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: I'm having a hard time following your question, because your expected output does not seem to really correspond to the query which appears below it.  Can you sync up all the data in your question?

Comment: `sum(c.vid) over (order by properties__createdate__value)`?

Comment: Read about window functions and `OVER()` : [doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/tutorial-window.html)

Comment: I've updated the code to better show what I currently have. No luck with sum(c.vid) over (order by c.properties__createdate__value). I believe I should use it in subquery?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can just replace `count(x.vid)` with `sum(x.vid) OVER(ORDER BY properties__createdate__value)`.

Here is a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/66e6e/3) exercising the idea. I built a table that replicates your example table. If you have the first two columns of the example built, you should be able to apply that line to it to create the running total.